# If $\sup_n f_n$ is integrable, does equality hold in Fatou's Lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am studying measure theory and I have a question regarding equality in Fatou's Lemma:

For any sequence of functions $\left\{ f_n \right\}$ that are in $L^+$,

$$\int \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n d\mu \leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n d\mu $$

I am wondering if there are any sufficient conditions for equality to hold.

I saw in this answer that if $\sup_n f_n$ is integrable, then equality holds where Davide quotes Dominated Converges Theorem for that.
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/545298/77767

However, DCT only works when the sequence of functions converges, I cannot see how that can be applied here. Is there any version of DCT that is stated using $\liminf$ instead of using $\lim$?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does it help writing $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g_n$ where $g_n:=\inf_{k\ge n}f_k$?

Comment: @nejimban I am not sure how this helps, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Application of DCT in your link was wrong and it has now been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality still need not hold. Consider $X=[0,2]$ with usual Lebesgue measure, and
\begin{align}
f_n=
\begin{cases}
\chi_{[0,1]}&\text{if $n$ odd}\\
\chi_{[1,2]}&\text{if $n$ even}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Draw a sketch of these functions. So $f_n$ alternates between a 'left-step' and a 'right-step' function. Then we have $\liminf f_n = 0$, and $\int f_n = 1$ for all $n$, so we have a strict inequality in Fatou $0<1$.

What we can say is that if $\sup f_n$ is integrable, then
\begin{align}
\int \liminf f_n\leq \liminf \int f_n \leq \limsup\int f_n \leq \int \limsup f_n.
\end{align}
The first inequality is usual Fatou, second always holds (a basic property about numbers); the final step requires the domination assumption; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4396849/568204)
for further remarks. Note that this chain of inequalities actually implies DCT because if we assume further that $\lim f_n$ exists, then $\liminf f_n = \limsup f_n$ (again a basic property of real numbers applied pointwise: limit exists in $[-\infty,\infty]$ if and only if $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are equal), and thus the first and last term of the inequality are the same thing, so all inequalities can be replaced by equalities.

Fatou's lemma is really just a general observation about integrals and limiting operations (and to be fully general we only consider $\liminf$). However, because of the weaker hypothesis (not-necessarily assuming convergence) the conclusions are weaker. Going one step further of making the domination assumption gives us the reverse Fatou inequality (the final inequality in the chain above). Going yet one step further and assuming pointwise a.e. convergence yields DCT.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! Does that mean there are no general conditions for Fatou's Lemma to hold with equality without the convergence of the sequence?

Comment: @Victor none that I know of

Comment: Notice that the reason why the inequality creeps in is because infimums of arbitrary functions do not commute with integrals; we only have an inequality. More explicitly, $\liminf f_n = \sup\limits_{n\geq 1}\left(\inf\limits_{k\geq n}f_k\right)$. The functions in brackets are increasing (weakly) with respect to $n$ so by monotone convergence, the supremum commutes with integral. But now we only have that integral of infimum $\leq$ infimum of integral (due to obvious monotonicity), and this is the issue. So you have to find some way to ensure equality at this step.

Comment: I see. Thanks for helping! I have a specific problem and I am trying to check if I can show the quality to hold.  What I have is that $f_n \geq 0$ and \begin{align}\liminf \int f_n = \limsup\int f_n = \int \limsup f_n=C>0. 
\end{align} and $\liminf f_n \leq C$ and $\limsup f_n \leq C$. Are these conditions sufficient for equality to hold? Or are these conditions sufficient to show that $f_n$ converges to C almost everywhere?

Comment: I think you meant let $X=[0,2]$.

Comment: @K.defaoite of course, thanks!

Comment: @peek-a-boo I just realized the example you gave served as a counterexample for the new conditions I posted in the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Equality rarely holds without convergence of $(f_n)$. Let $f_n=f$ for $n$ even and $g$ for $n$ odd. Then equality would mean $\int (f \wedge g)=(\int f )\wedge (\int g)$ which is not true in general.

Note: $\int (f \wedge g)=(\int f )\wedge (\int g)$ if and only if either $f \leq g$ a.e. or $g \leq f $ a.e. Proof: $(\int f )\wedge (\int g)$  is either $\int f$ of $\int g$. Suppose it is $\int f$. Then $\int (f-f\wedge g)=0$ and $f-f\wedge g$ is a non-negative measurable function. Hence, it is $0$ a.e. But $f=f\wedge g$ a.e. implies $f \leq g $ a.e. In  the case when $(\int f )\wedge (\int g) =\int g$ we get $g \leq f$ a.e.

Thus, you get a  counter-example by taking $f=\chi_A,g=\chi_B$ where $A$ and $B$ are any two disjoint sets with positive measure, say two disjoint open intervals.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I can only accept one answer, sorry about that.